# How do I track down where/why I get this message "Incompatible runner: OctopusDeploy: Create release"

Tags: octopus-deploy, teamcity-9.0

I have completed fresh installs of TeamCity and Octopus, I have previously got all of the builds working and producing a build in team city and then manually creating a release in octopus and releasing. All good.

I want to get to the next level of automation and have the end of my TeamCity build create a release and deploy it to my Prelive environment in octopus, when I configure this I get the message in TeamCity.

I have the TeamCity plugin downloaded and installed, I have restarted the Services. I am on Teamcity 9.1.1 and 2.6.3.37 is my Octopus plugin for teamcity downloaded from the http://octopusdeploy.com/downloads page. Octopus version is 3.0.11.... I have copied the settings from another server (which is working in this fashion)... so I know my options and selections should be correct

however when I say "build" I get the following message

"Incompatible runner: OctopusDeploy: Create release"

Obviously I have something wrong-but my question HOW do I find out what it is... I cant seem to find why it cant do the octopus create release for me?

Documentation on the website(s) is helpful but maddeningly incomplete when it comes to troubleshooting.... So what I am asking is what log file where gives me some clues as to what's failing...

How do I troubleshoot this one

Regards Julian

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like it may be a faulty installation of the Octopus plugin for TeamCity. Someone else got the same error message: http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/problems/28065-teamcity-plugin

Comment: I have tried both just putting the zip file in via the upload (didnt work) and extracting the zip file and placing it into the folder (didnt work)...But what I am asking is how I find out WHY its incompatible.... where is the log and or more detail I cant seem to find how to trouble shoot and am left with making guesses and being random

Comment: Try hunting for your error message in the teamcity-server.log file. The location of TeamCIty logs is described in https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/TeamCity+Server+Logs. And there is a description of how to install a TeamCity plugin in https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Installing+Additional+Plugins

Comment: Been through all of the logs and there was no error message in there relating to this problem... I feel that the problem of incompatible runners does not give you enough to trace why. But thanks

Comment: This is correct and here's the fix: 1) stop TC service 2) delete the TC+OD plugin zip and `.unpacked/Octopus.TeamCity` folder 3) start the TC service 4) upload the new .zip through the UI 5) restart the TC service => then you should be up and running again :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, originally as in Octopus 1.3 you used to extract the RAR File and place in the plugins directory, now doing this appears not to work, in fact NOT unpacking the zip file was the solution. I a) deleted the files that were there from the Octopus plugin, b) restarted TeamCity, c) used the Administrator upload plugin process d) restarted team city for belt and braces safety and then d) it worked.

The only takeaway for Octopus and Team City people is please be giving us the context of WHY something wont work, the log files had nothing in them relating to this and with no idea of why it was trial and error to install. This makes the user experience of setting up team city and octopus a bit of a trial and if you solved this and made it smoother we would be happier using
 anyway I got it working thatnks for your suggestions